# Angular 6 - data loaded in console log but not displayed in html

Tags: angular

I have a global service `userAuthService` that is fired up as long as auth token is valid in my app, then subscribe the service in Profile component to load a logged in user data. I could see the data is loaded in console log but data is NOT shown in html until I route away from Profile component and route back, then data is shown. In short, if I route to Profile component from other routes, data is shown, else if Profile component is the first page where my app loads, data is never shown.

user-auth-service:

```
  private identity = new BehaviorSubject(<Identity>{});
  public identity$ = this.identity.asObservable();

  private isValidToken = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public isValidToken$ = this.isValidToken.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private router: Router,
    private apiService: ApiService,
  ) {
    this.store.select('tokens').subscribe((tokens: AuthToken) => {
      this.tokens = tokens;
      if (tokens && this.hasValidToken()) {
        this.isValidToken.next(true);
      } else {
        this.isValidToken.next(false);
      }
    });

    this.store.select('identity').subscribe((identity: any) => {
      if (identity.identity) {
        this.setIdentity(identity.identity);
      } 
    });
  }  

  setIdentity(identity: Identity) {
    this.identity.next(identity);
  }

  getIdentity() {
   this.store.dispatch(new identityActions.GetIdentityAction());
  }
```

app.component.ts:

```
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private userAuthService: UserAuthService,
  ) {
    this.storeSub = this.store.select('tokens').subscribe((tokens: AuthToken) => {
      this.validToken = this.userAuthService.hasValidToken();
    });

    this.tokenSub = this.userAuthService.isValidToken$.subscribe((bool: boolean) => {
      this.validToken = bool;
      if (bool) {
        this.userAuthService.getIdentity();
      }
    });
  }
```

profile.component.ts:

```
  constructor(
    private userAuthService: UserAuthService
  ) {
    this.idenSub = this.userAuthService.identity$.subscribe((res: Identity) => {
      this.identity = res;
      console.log(this.identity);
    });
  }
```

profile.component.html:

```
<div>{{identity?.email}}</div>
```

Comment: start by trying a `{{identity | json}}`

Comment: why you're affecting the service to a variable ? try to remove the affectaion.

Comment: @Cétia I tried, it shows blank object as '{}'.

Comment: @selemmn can you elaborate a bit more pls?

Comment: what shows `console.log(this.identity);` ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID the object of `this.identity` including basic details such as email, userId, etc.

Comment: Could you edit and put the information you see in the `console.log(this.identity);`

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn i guess that you are re-assigning a new value to `identity` somewhere , can you please verify ? or show more code so we can detect the problem

Comment: Alright, I just copied the same code to a new component I just created and it works properly. I doubt the routing issue or something else corrupted my old component that I can't understand. Thank you all anw.

Answer (score 0):

You could create `identity$` subject - 
`public identity$ = this.userAuthService.identity$`;

and subscribe in your template using pipe async:

```
<div *ngIf="identity$ | async as identity">
   {{identity.email}}
</div>
```

please tell me if it hepled

Comment: The same code I posted works fine in other components, so perhaps my Profile component is corrupted or routing issue. But now everything works fine, I would try your solution next time maybe, thank you anyway.